# Atom build from source

Tags: git, macos, atom-editor

I'm trying to achieve the same effect used [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/11790#) and modify my files in Atom.

[image: Atom Text Editor]
What does the below mean and how do I implement this?

```
So you'll have to build from source.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to download Atom source files from [Github](https://github.com/atom/atom) and follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/tree/master/docs/build-instructions) according to your OS.